# extracting list-in-a-list-in-a-list to build dataframe in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, purrr

I am trying to build a data frame with book id, title, author, rating, collection, start and finish date from the LibraryThing api with my personal data. I am able to get a nested list fairly easily, and I have figured out how to build a data frame with everything but the dates (perhaps in not the best way but it works). My issue is with the dates. 
The list I'm working with normally has 20 elements, but it adds the startfinishdates element only if I added dates to the book in my account. This is causing two issues:

- If it was always there, I could extract it like everything else and it would have NA most of the time, and I could use cbind to get it lined up correctly with the other information
- When I extract it using the name, and get an object with less elements, I don't have a way to join it back to everything else (it doesn't have the book id)

Ultimately, I want to build this data frame and an answer that tells me how to pull out the book id and associate it with each startfinishdate so I can join on book id is acceptable. I would just add that to the code I have.

I'm also open to learning a better approach from the jump and re-designing the entire thing as I have not worked with lists much in R and what I put together was after much trial and error. I do want to use R though, as ultimately I am going to use this to create an R Markdown page for my web site (for instance, a plot that shows finish dates of books).

You can run the code below and get the data (no api key required).

```
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)
library(assertr)

data<-fromJSON("http://www.librarything.com/api_getdata.php?userid=cau83&key=392812157&max=450&showCollections=1&responseType=json&showDates=1")

books.lst<-data$books

#create df from json
create.df<-function(item){
  df<-map_df(.x=books.lst,~.x[[item]])
  df2 <- t(df)
  return(df2)
}

ids<-create.df(1)
titles<-create.df(2)
ratings<-create.df(12)
authors<-create.df(4)

#need to get the book id when i build the date df's
startdates.df<-map_df(.x=books.lst,~.x$startfinishdates) %>% select(started_stamp,started_date)
finishdates.df<-map_df(.x=books.lst,~.x$startfinishdates) %>% select(finished_stamp,finished_date)
collections.df<-map_df(.x=books.lst,~.x$collections)
#from assertr: will create a vector of same length as df with all values concatenated
collections.v<-col_concat(collections.df, sep = ", ")

#assemble df
books.df<-as.data.frame(cbind(ids,titles,authors,ratings,collections.v)) 
names(books.df)<-c("ID","Title","Author","Rating","Collections")
books.df<-books.df %>% mutate(ID=as.character(ID),Title=as.character(Title),Author=as.character(Author),
                              Rating=as.character(Rating),Collections=as.character(Collections))
```

Comment: > I'm also open to learning a better approach Since it's unclear what you hope to do once the JSON data has been ingested into R, it's difficult to know what alternative approaches are admissible, but since your data is JSON, you might wish to consider a JSON-oriented tool such as [tag:jq]. jq in particular makes the efficient querying and updating of JSON documents very easy.

Comment: I updated the question with information on why I want/need it in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is outside the `tidyverse` meta-package. Using base-R you can make it work using the following code.

`Map` will apply the user defined function to each element of `data$books` which is provided in the argument and extract the required fields for your `data.frame`. `Reduce` will take all the individual dataframes and merge them (or reduce) to a single data.frame `booksdf`.

```
library(jsonlite)
data<-fromJSON("http://www.librarything.com/api_getdata.php?userid=cau83&key=392812157&max=450&showCollections=1&responseType=json&showDates=1")

booksdf=Reduce(function(x,y){rbind(x,y)},
    Map(function(x){
lenofelements = length(x)

if(lenofelements>20){
  if(!is.null(x$startfinishdates$started_date)){
      started_date = x$startfinishdates$started_date
  }else{
      started_date=NA
  }

  if(!is.null(x$startfinishdates$started_stamp)){
      started_stamp = x$startfinishdates$started_date
  }else{
      started_stamp=NA
  }

  if(!is.null(x$startfinishdates$finished_date)){
      finished_date = x$startfinishdates$finished_date
  }else{
      finished_date=NA
  }

  if(!is.null(x$startfinishdates$finished_stamp)){
     finished_stamp = x$startfinishdates$finished_stamp
  }else{
     finished_stamp=NA
  }

}else{
    started_stamp = NA
    started_date = NA
    finished_stamp = NA
    finished_date = NA
}
book_id = x$book_id
title = x$title
author = x$author_fl
rating = x$rating
collections = paste(unlist(x$collections),collapse = ",")

return(data.frame(ID=book_id,Title=title,Author=author,Rating=rating,
Collections=collections,Started_date=started_date,Started_stamp=started_stamp,
Finished_date=finished_date,Finished_stamp=finished_stamp))
},data$books))
```

Comment: thank you. I want to have time to both test, and understand this. I will be able to do that later today.

Comment: @ChrisUmphlett Added a bit more explanation.

Comment: The if/else sequence makes total sense. I got so bogged down with the list I probably could have used if/else with my original code and gotten something similar to work.

Comment: I would appreciate you helping me understand it a bit more. The `x` in reduce(), rbind() and map() is data$books right? What is `y`? I am familar with map() but don't understand how it's used here, and I didn't know reduce(). I read some about reduce() but it doesn't mean much to me. Can you briefly describe they're doing to this data?

Comment: @ChrisUmphlett `x` in `Map()` is every element of the list `data$books`. `Map()` is used to apply a function (user-defined in this case) to all the elements of a list or array. Output of `Map()` is a list of `data.frame`s for each book. `Reduce()` takes `x` and `y` which are supposed to be objects of exactly the same type and then used to merge them together. It's quite similar to the Map-Reduce construct of Big-data, where huge data is spilt into chunks, applied a function or processed using Map and then combined back using Reduce. `x` & `y` in reduce are data.frames which are output of Map.